# Python error WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.'

Tags: python

I am new to python and am trying to run a prewritten program but keep recieving an error here is the whole error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\source\python\pill.py", line 29, in <module>
   ser.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 66, in    open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr,       ctypes.WinError()))
     SerialException: could not open port 'COM7': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

I am the admin as well

Comment: Do you use elevated prompt? Do you really have COM7 port? Use device manager to check.

Comment: Yes I do have that com port in use and im going threw idle and just hitting run

Comment: Try right-clicking the command icon and selecting "run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

You may have another program using the COM port, for example a test program like `firmata_test.exe` that our course work told use to use.

One course module told us to run that program, which is a Windows executable that opens the COM port and monitors the various pins on the board and lets us toggle their state High or Low.  The next module told us to run some Python code in the IDLE code editor that would connect to the board and write to the pin state to turn an LED on and off.  The Python code failed with the `Access is denied` message, because the COM port was already in use by `firmata_test.exe`, though the error message did not mention this specifically (because the Python code did not know why it could not open the port, only that it could not).

Close any other software such as `firmata_test.exe` that may be using the COM port and run your Python code again.